# CLion - How can I debug the external libraries of my CMake project without building them?

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, clion

I am trying to port a Visual Studio project over to CMake using CLion, but I'm struggling to get proper debugging functionality working, because CLion doesn't let me "step into" a function that is defined in an external library. Take the following code as an example:

```cpp
#include <afxwin.h>
int main() {
    CDialog dialog;
    dialog.Create("test"); // Breakpoint!
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio, I can step into the `CDialog::Create` function, since the MFC framework includes the full source code as well as the debugging symbols in the Windows SDK.

However, if I try to debug the same program under CMake in CLion (still using the Visual Studio toolchain), the debugger simply steps over the function when I try to step into it.

Similarly, if I break on a line of code that was called by an external library (e.g. a callback), Visual Studio displays a fully usable call stack and allows me to navigate in the external code, but CLion only displays memory addresses and the disassembly of the calling library. Sadly I do not speak x86 assembly, so this is not useful.

Is there any way I can configure the CLion debugger to use the source code of external libraries, where it's available? Note that I **do not** want to include these libraries in my CMake project as build targets, as that would unnecessarily overcomplicate my projects.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt, in case it's helpful:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(untitled)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

---

**EDIT:** I have tried adding the following URLs to the "Symbol Servers" list under Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger. Now I get debug info about the core C libraries, but still no debug support for MFC:

```py
https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/atlmfc/lib/x86
file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Preview/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/atlmfc/lib/x64
```

---

**EDIT 2:** It looks like I can "force-step into" the function now with the symbol servers enabled, but at first it takes me to a `jmpl   *0xfd01b4` instruction. If I "step into" again, then it finally takes me to the function's first instruction (still disassembly view), but this time CLion complains that it cannot find the source file (dlgcore.cpp) and prompts me to select it. If I manually select the file, then it finally lets me step through the source code of the external library.

This is still not desirable, because I have to step into each function twice, and I have to manually select the source file every time.

Comment: how do you tell cmake to link with the external library? do they have a `CMakeLists.txt` themselfs?

Comment: @0xbachmann For this particular library (AFX/MFC) I don't have to tell CMake to link it, since the library is part of the Windows SDK, and because I'm using the Visual Studio toolchain in CLion, it is linked by default.

Comment: try to add `find_package(MFC)` to your `CMakeLists.txt`. As Clion is very dependent on the build system i suspect, that because your cmake file does not explicitly contain any information about MFC, clion is not able to find the required files. You can also check if `find_package` was unsuccessful with a `if(NOT MFC_FOUND) ...
endif()`

Comment: @0xbachmann Unfortunately that did not solve the issue. I've also tried disabling the default `mfc140d.lib` with `/NODEFAULTLIB` and manually linking it using `target_link_libraries`, but I get the same exact results that I described in my 2nd edit.